# How to refer to user's home directory in configuration.nix?

Tags: nix

I can't seem to refer to `${users.users.username.home}` within the same file where this configuration is set up:

> undefined variable 'users'

How should I refer to this piece of configuration from within the same file? In case it's relevant, both `users.users.username` and the reference are in a file included by `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just needed `config.` at the start of the reference: `${config.users.users.username.home}`.